# addEventListener inside constructor es6 class get fired ones on init and never agian

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm new to es6 classes and cant quite understand why the following behaves like it does:

```
  let scrollElement = document.querySelector(".foo");
  scrollElement.addEventListener("scroll", logSomething());

  logSomething(){
    console.log("hi");
  }
```

Will output "hi" in my console every time I scroll. This is what I want. Now I try to do the same thing but with a designated class to group all the scroll behaviour:

```
   class scrollHelper{
        constructor(scrollElement){
            scrollElement.addEventListener("scroll", this.logSomething());
      }


      logSomething(){
        console.log("hi");
      }
   }


  let scrollElement = document.querySelector(".foo");

  new scrollHelper(scrollElement)
```

But instead of logging hi every time I scroll it logs "hi" ones when the class instance is created and never after that.

Could someone tell me why this happens and what I'm doing wrong to get the same result as the first example.

Kinds regards,
Merijn

Comment: It’s `scrollElement.addEventListener("scroll", this.logSomething);`. You need to pass a function _reference_, not _call_ the function.

Comment: Because there's no such function. You have to call the method you need. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback for using methods as callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to invoke `logSomething`, you need to pass it as a handler to be invoked during the event `scroll`.

Also make sure the div is even scrollable.

```js
class scrollHelper{
  constructor(scrollElement){
    scrollElement.addEventListener("scroll", this.logSomething);
  }


  logSomething(){
    console.log("hi");
  }
}


let scrollElement = document.querySelector(".foo");
console.log(scrollElement);

new scrollHelper(scrollElement)
```

```css
.foo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: red;
}

#tall {
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div id="tall"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Damn that was stupid. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
scrollElement.addEventListener("scroll", logSomething());
```

You're invoking the function immediately. You want to pass in a reference instead.

```
scrollElement.addEventListener("scroll", logSomething);
```

Notice lack of parenthesis.

Comment: I get a error: Uncaught ReferenceError: logSomething is not defined. Need to be this.logSomething but indeed. works like a charm

Comment: I was referring to your first bit of "pseudo"-code. If you plan on referring to the class instance from within your logSomething method, you'll want to bind "this" or make use of an arrow function, otherwise you'll run into further trouble. I'd recommend searching stack overflow for examples or reading about "this".